# VBA Range using Active.cell.column and range of rows

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a statement:

```
Range("C4:C6").Value = "No"
```

And I need the column letter to be defined using.ActiveCell.Column and all is fine when I have a range of one specific row, which would be like:

```
Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "No"
```

But how do I write "Range("C4:C6")" in the same manner as code above that has .activecell.column

Hope someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Range(Cells(4, ActiveCell.Column),Cells(6, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = "No"
```

This would be equivalent to range starting at row 4 and ending in whatever column is Activecell, but row 6.

Comment: @Eduards Forgot one parenthesis in the end. Check updated answer

Comment: That 3 means column number 3, so it means column C actually :). Cells can be combined with Range this way, to target a specific range, instead of A1 notation (A1 means notation like `C3` or `C3:D6`

Comment: It depends on how you use it. Reading your original post I thought you wanted a range starting at `C3` and ending in any column, but row 6. But your code works too if you want to do it in the active column. My answer just tried to help you out to find the proper code, and I think we got it :)

Comment: We did! I edited your answer to be exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!